# SQL Sub Query with outer LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql

I need to select all rows from `table A` and select matching rows from `table B` if the `table B` rows match the `table B` select where clause.  Here is my outer `LEFT JOIN` with sub query, but it fails.  Can someone please help?

```
SELECT A.WRDWHSE,
       A.WRDRTID,
       A.WRDRPTLIN
FROM CWDDEV.WRTEMSTDP AS A 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT B.RHRTID,
                  B.RHRTE, 
                  B.RHSTAT, 
                  B.RHPRTT 
           FROM PIRF3.RTEHED
           WHERE B.RHWHSE=003 and 
                 ((B.RHSTSD =20151111 and B.RHSTST >=060000 ) or (B.RHSTSD=20151112 and B.RHSTST <=055959 )) and
                 B.RHTYPE NOT IN ('W') and 
                 (B.RHRTE NOT LIKE 'EMP%') and
                 B.RHSTAT IN (1, 3, 4, 5, 6)) AS B                                                     
ON A.WRDWHSE=B.RHWHSE and A.WRDRTID=B.RHRTE
WHERE A.WRDWHSE=003     
ORDER BY A.WRDRPTLIN
```

Comment: Please edit your question and put some effort into formatting your query.  Hint:  four spaces at the beginning of a line are used for formatting code.

Comment: Looks fine, although you're not even select columns from B in your output. How is it failing?

Comment: B is the Alias known to the outer select.  B is unknown to the inner select as it's not in scope yet; thus B.RHRTID is invalid RHRTID would be valid. or you need to alter `PIRF3.RTEHED` to  `PIRF3.RTEHED as B`  However, we don't know what's wrong  (fails in what way? with error, no data what?) so I doubt this is really the problem.

Comment: Also `B.RHWHSE` isn't in the selected values in the subquery; so it can't join on it.  This is likely the problem.  Add `RHWHSE` to the inner select.  Also I don't know why you need b.RHWHSE=003 as the outer select will eliminate them on the join.  Also 003 is numeric data.  If it's string you need to wrap it in single quotes `'`  otherwise why the leading 00s?

Comment: Actually I originally had "PIRF3.RTEHED as B" but I changed the code because of something I saw in a QA board.  The SQL now is back to "PIRF3.RTEHED as B".  The error I get is A is not a valid token and the message is pointing to the  A.WRDWHSE in the ON part of the statement.

Comment: yeah that's because B.RHWHSE isn't in the sub selects selected list of values.  Add B.RHWHSE to the selected values of the subselect after for example: `SELECT B.RHRTID,
                  B.RHRTE, 
                  B.RHSTAT, 
                  B.RHPRTT, B.RHWHSE`  (See prior comment for a few things to consider)  You have some implicit conversions occurring which may be negatively affecting your results.

Comment: I included the B=RHWHSE to the inner select and I'm still getting the error  "Token A was not valid. Valid tokens: ON FULL LEFT CROSS INNER RIGHT".   Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Run the sub select independent of the join.  Does it work?  if not what error does it present?  Evaluate each piece independent of the whole so you can isolate the issue.  Right now I'm still concerned the sub-select isn't working.

Comment: Great thought to run the sub query alone.  I did that and the sub query runs fine with the results I expected.  The sub query with the LEFT JOIN still does not work, throwing the same error as mentioned above.  Stand alone sub query:                                                                                       SELECT B.RHWHSE, B.RHRTID, B.RHRTE, B.RHSTAT, B.RHPRTT FROM PIRF3.RTEHED AS B WHERE B.RHWHSE=003 and ((B.RHSTSD =20151111 and B.RHSTST >=060000 ) or (B.RHSTSD=20151112 and B.RHSTST <=055959 )) and B.RHTYPE NOT IN ('W') and (B.RHRTE NOT LIKE 'EMP%') and B.RHSTAT IN (1, 3, 4, 5, 6)

Comment: If the inner query works and the outer one does with out the inner then the problem MUST be on either the join syntax, or missing records don't have the data you expect (perhaps there's a hidden extra character)   Where are we at here? based on @shawnt00's work and comments I think you have the query running it's just missing a single record  For that missing record I would look at the length of each field on the join for that specific record.  My guess is there's an extra space or hidden character (non-display character) preventing the join!

Answer (score 2):

Here are my initial thoughts inline with your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    CWDDEV.WRTEMSTDP A LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
    SELECT
        B.RHWHSE, B.RHRTE,
        B.RHRTID, B.RHSTAT, B.RHPRTT /* are these going to be used? */
    FROM PIRF3.RTEHED B
    WHERE
            B.RHWHSE = 003 /* why all the leading zeros? are these numeric or a char? */
        AND (
               /* if these are really dates then these won't work */
               (B.RHSTSD = 20151111 AND B.RHSTST >= 060000)
            OR (B.RHSTSD = 20151112 AND B.RHSTST <= 055959)
        )
        AND B.RHTYPE NOT IN ('W')
        AND B.RHRTE NOT LIKE 'EMP%'
        AND B.RHSTAT IN (1, 3, 4, 5, 6)
    ) B_outer /* inside and outside have different names */
        ON A.WRDWHSE = B_outer.RHWHSE AND A.WRDRTID = B_outer.RHRTE
WHERE A.WRDWHSE = 003
ORDER BY A.WRDRPTLIN
```

EDIT: Based on the conversation below I'm willing to consider a DB2/AS400 bug. Your scenario for using a left join is very common. But here are some variations on the query that might work or help figure something out.

Eliminate redundant condition:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    CWDDEV.WRTEMSTDP A LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
    SELECT B.RHWHSE, B.RHRTE, B.RHRTID, B.RHSTAT, B.RHPRTT
    FROM PIRF3.RTEHED B
    WHERE
        (
               B.RHSTSD = 20151111 AND B.RHSTST >= 060000
            OR B.RHSTSD = 20151112 AND B.RHSTST <= 055959
        )
        AND B.RHTYPE <> 'W'
        AND B.RHRTE NOT LIKE 'EMP%'
        AND B.RHSTAT IN (1, 3, 4, 5, 6)
    ) B_outer
        ON A.WRDWHSE = B_outer.RHWHSE AND A.WRDRTID = B_outer.RHRTE
WHERE A.WRDWHSE = 3 AND A.WRDRTID = 73
ORDER BY A.WRDRPTLIN
```

Common table expression (CTE):

```
WITH ROUTES AS ( /* this might not be valid if your platform is old */
    SELECT
        B.RHWHSE, B.RHRTE, B.RHRTID, B.RHSTAT, B.RHPRTT
    FROM PIRF3.RTEHED B
    WHERE
        (
               B.RHSTSD = 20151111 AND B.RHSTST >= 060000
            OR B.RHSTSD = 20151112 AND B.RHSTST <= 055959
        )
        AND B.RHTYPE <> 'W'
        AND B.RHRTE NOT LIKE 'EMP%'
        AND B.RHSTAT IN (1, 3, 4, 5, 6)
)
SELECT *
FROM CWDDEV.WRTEMSTDP A LEFT OUTER JOIN ROUTES B
    ON A.WRDWHSE = B.RHWHSE AND A.WRDRTID = B.RHRTE
WHERE A.WRDWHSE = 3 AND A.WRDRTID = 73
ORDER BY A.WRDRPTLIN
```

Union:

```
SELECT
    A.WRDWHSE, A.WRDRTID, A.WRDRPTLIN,
    B.RHRTE, B.RHSTAT, B.RHPRTT
FROM
    CWDDEV.WRTEMSTDP A INNER JOIN PIRF3.RTEHED B
        ON A.WRDWHSE = B_outer.RHWHSE AND A.WRDRTID = B_outer.RHRTE
WHERE
        A.WRDWHSE = 3 AND A.WRDRTID = 73
    (
           B.RHSTSD = 20151111 AND B.RHSTST >= 060000
        OR B.RHSTSD = 20151112 AND B.RHSTST <= 055959
    )
    AND B.RHTYPE <> 'W'
    AND B.RHRTE NOT LIKE 'EMP%'
    AND B.RHSTAT IN (1, 3, 4, 5, 6)
UNION ALL
SELECT
    A.WRDWHSE, A.WRDRTID, A.WRDRPTLIN,
    NULL AS RHRTE, NULL AS RHSTAT, NULL AS RHPRTT
FROM CWDDEV.WRTEMSTDP A
WHERE A.WRDWHSE = 3 AND A.WRDRTID = 73 AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM PIRF3.RTEHED B
    WHERE
            A.WRDWHSE = B.RHWHSE AND A.WRDRTID = B.RHRTE
        AND (
               B.RHSTSD = 20151111 AND B.RHSTST >= 060000
            OR B.RHSTSD = 20151112 AND B.RHSTST <= 055959
        )
        AND B.RHTYPE <> 'W'
        AND B.RHRTE NOT LIKE 'EMP%'
        AND B.RHSTAT IN (1, 3, 4, 5, 6)
    )
ORDER BY A.WRDRPTLIN
```

You could also try a view or a temp table if you really need to get it to work. It sounds like the nested loop you mentioned may be the best workaround for you.

Comment: Thanks shawnt00.  I didn't know about the OUTER specification, I'll have to read more on that.  Your suggestion produces the same result as if I do just a straight ahead LEFT JOIN without the sub query.  The problem is I'm getting all rows from the A.WRTEMSTDP table except one row.  The missing row is for the row with A.WRDRTID = 73.   There are rows in the B.RTEHED table where A.WRDRTID=B.RHRTE, the problem is they are rows that are outside the date range.  The JOIN is satisfied and finds a match but the row is not included because the WHERE clause drops it on the non-match on the date range.

Comment: There are rows in the B.RTEHED table where A.WRDRTID=73 and B.RHRTE=73, the problem is they are rows that are outside the date range.My desired result would be to include the A.WRDRTID=73 row as a LEFT OUTER JOIN as if it did not find a match in B.RTEHED.  I'm tempted to create to separate queries with two loops, i.e. while table A {  while table B {.............}}

Comment: `OUTER` is usually optional and it means exactly the same thing. What is the `WRDWHSE` of the row with `WRDRTID` 73? You have a filter on the outer query too.

Comment: Thanks again shawnt00.  It's a match, 003.  I know the query is somewhat complex and when I try to explain it seems a bit cumbersome, I hope you're able to understand my objective and desired results.  I think you do but please let me know if there is anything that is not making sense.  Thanks

Comment: Actually your query is not really complicated at all. The only way for rows from A to be excluded is if `WRDWHSE` is not equal to 3.

Comment: I think there might be an implicit cast going on. Try `A.WRDWHSE = '003'`

Comment: Thanks.  I know there are 003(warehouse),73(route) rows in both tables.  The first table is a route master and the second table is route orders.  I want to list all rows in the route master, and I want to include any rows from the route order file that are within the requested date range for the route master row being processed on each iteration of the loop.  The problem is there are warehouse 003 route 73 rows in both tables, however, there are not any rows in the route orders table within the date range....so in this case I want only the route master row for route 73, and not getting it.

Comment: All I can think of is the LEFT JOIN must be satisfied because there are warehouse 003 route 73 rows in both tables but the route 73 row(s) are filtered out because of the where clause.

Comment: The leading zeros are not significant unless these are being stored as strings/character data. I've already said that the only way to eliminate A's rows is in the `where` clause and I'm asking you to look closer at the values in column `WRDWHSE`.

Comment: whs is numeric and route is character.  The raw query without any variable values is......$sql="SELECT * FROM " .$cwdlib . ".WRTEMSTDP A LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT B.RHWHSE, B.RHRTID, B.RHRTE, B.RHSTAT, B.RHPRTT FROM " . $lib . ".RTEHED B WHERE B.RHWHSE=" .$whse . " and ((B.RHSTSD =" .$fdtstr . " and B.RHSTST >=060000 ) or (B.RHSTSD=" .$tdtstr . " and B.RHSTST <=055959 )) and B.RHTYPE NOT IN ('" . "W" . "') and (B.RHRTE NOT LIKE '" . "EMP%" . "') and B.RHSTAT IN (".$sqlrtestat.")  B_outer ON A.WRDWHSE=B_outer.RHWHSE and A.WRDRTID=B_outer.RHRTE WHERE A.WRDWHSE=" .$whse . " ORDER BY A.WRDRPTLIN "

Comment: that's tough to get edited properly in this text box.  I'm doing this in a php script so I hope I removed all the ; etc.... and didn't remove anything I shouldn't have trying to get so you could see the raw sql statement with the variables as opposed to their inserted values

Comment: Does this query give you everything you need on the A side? `SELECT * FROM CWDDEV.WRTEMSTDP WHERE WRDWHSE = 3`

Comment: $whse comes from a prompt.  I hear and appreciate what you're saying but the inner query runs fine with the same leading zeros, it's just when I include the LEFT JOIN when I run into problems.  BTW, the PHP is running via Zend on an IBM iSeries connecting to a DB2 database.

Comment: Thanks again shawnt00. yes the outer query runs fine alone.  The outer query is:   SELECT A.WRDWHSE, A.WRDRTID, A.WRDRPTLIN FROM CWDDEV.WRTEMSTDP AS A 
 WHERE A.WRDWHSE=003 ORDER BY A.WRDRPTLIN

Comment: I have been asking about the outer query. Regardless of leading zeros does the outer query actually give you what you wanted? (A is outer; B is inner.)

Comment: yes, I get all rows from outer query on table A as expected.  I only lose the table A route 73 row when I add the inner query

Comment: Does your server or query tool have any settings that limit the number of rows coming back? Does descending order show the missing row?

Comment: I don't believe so.  That's a good thought though.  The thing is route 73 is about 2/3 the way down in the expected result set.  The route 73 row should show just before the route 83 row.  The route 83 row and about 20+ rows subsequent are listed.  BTW, I've executed queries with many more rows than this and have not had a problem.  There's something about the syntax of this query.  Maybe I'm trying something SQL is not capable of handling

Comment: I haven't specified descending order.  I need the result set to be listed in ascending order by WRDRPTLIN (report line number).  This PHP displays the results in a browser session and then will generate a spreadsheet upon request so sequencing by report line number is a critical part of the logic

Comment: Change the inner query to this and tell me what happens: `SELECT CAST(NULL AS INT) AS RHWHSE, CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(10)) AS RHRTE` ..

Comment: Thanks shawnt00.  RHRTE is actually a length of 5, should I change the VARCHAR(10) to VARCHAR(5)?  Also, do I insert this in the area that the columns are specified for the inner query and leave the rest of the inner as is?

Comment: Yes, I was just looking to return all the same rows with null values, so just the `select` clause. You can change to length 5 but it probably shouldn't matter.

Comment: This gave me a result set that includes route 73.  I need to see if this is what I'm expecting or just something different....SELECT * FROM CWDDEV.WRTEMSTDP LEFT OUTER JOIN   
(SELECT CAST(NULL AS INT) AS RHWHSE,  
 CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(5)) AS RHRTE, 
 RHRTID, RHSTAT, RHPRTT   
 FROM PIRF3.RTEHED   
 WHERE RHWHSE=003 and ((RHSTSD =20151111 and RHSTST >=060000 ) or
 (RHSTSD=20151112 and RHSTST <=055959 ))   
 and RHTYPE NOT IN ('W') and (RHRTE NOT LIKE 'EMP%')             
 and RHSTAT IN (1, 3, 4, 5, 6))  
outer ON WRDWHSE=RHWHSE and WRDRTID=RHRTE  
   WHERE WRDWHSE=003 ORDER BY WRDRPTLIN

Comment: Thanks shawnt00.  I'll analyze the result set and let you know

Comment: Now I'm only getting all the Route Master rows the Route Orders rows are all NULL, I guess due to the date range filter.  Somehow I need to combine this Cast modification to only work when there are no rows in the date range, in addition to including all matches between the route master and route orders that are within the date range.

Comment: That query was just a sanity check/troubleshooting. There are no route orders because all the data was nulled out and thus none of the rows matched up in the join. This just demonstrates that the left join does not eliminate any of the data from A that you need.

Comment: Thanks shawnt00.  Well I don't know where to go with this now.  It seems so simple yet I can't get it to work.  I simply need all rows from the route master table for the warehouse ID entered in the prompt, and any orders from the route order table that match the selected route master warehouse and route ID's that fall within the requested date range.

Comment: What database platform is this? DB2?

Comment: The database platform is DB2 on an IBM i (AS400).  I'm accessing the database from a PHP script in a Zend (server) environment via a DB2_connect

Comment: Are you trying these queries against the db directly or are you doing it thru the php script? It would be good to confirm the behavior is independent of the php environment.

Comment: yes sir, I log onto the IBM i (AS400) and start an SQL session on that machine against that database as a check.  I am also making the same mods to the PHP script and running it from the Zend server environment.  Same results either way.  I feel like I'm dancing around the answer......so close yet lost.  You've been a big help shawnt00.  Even though we haven't solved the problem I've learned some good things from our conversation.  You've put a lot of time in on this trying to help me and I understand if you're ready to signoff on this one, otherwise please let me know if have any other ideas

Comment: shawnt00, thank you for your generosity with your time.

Comment: Sorry if I came off as cranky at first. Most of the new users with low rep just expect you to fix their problem and offer little feedback. Feel free to come back to this if you find anything new. Not finding a solution is going to bug me :)

Comment: + just for the effort involved here.

Comment: hey shawnt00, not at all, np I'm just grateful for any assistance.  I hear ya about figuring this out.  I prefer to figure things out on my own and not ask for help, and in fact spent quite a bit time on it before signing up for this site.  I'm glad there's a resource such as stack over flow.  I'll give the details from a different perspective, maybe that will help,  but I think I'm just going to go to plan B and have two sql's and loop's, first over the route master table and then inside that, one over the route orders table.......while rtemstr{...while rteords{.....}.......}.  Thanks again

Comment: I have a route master table consisting of all valid routes.  Next I have a route orders table that consists of customer orders by route. Included in the route orders table rows are columns for warehouse, route id, date for order to ship, status of open, shipped, cancelled, etc...  Typically each day has it's own set of routes (customer order deliveries) that run for that day.  Management wants to see what routes and corresponding orders are to be shipped or have shipped for a given day.

Comment: Almost always there are orders for a route on the day that route runs, however, on rare occasion a route will be scheduled to run but there are no orders for that day/route.  I'm working on generating a browser based inquiry that will show all routes that are assigned for a given date (prompted) and then list all orders within each route.  I need to be able to list all routes for the request day regardless if there are any orders.  I then want to list the orders assigned to each route for the requested day(date range).  A route may have had orders the last day it ran but not on this day.

Comment: In this case there will be rows in the route orders table for that route but just not for that day.  This is where I thought a LEFT JOIN ON warehouse and route over the route master (table A) and the route orders (table B) with a sub query over the route orders only retrieving rows for that day, so if there were no orders for that route for that day then the LEFT JOIN (table A) would not see any rows for that route and that day and return a NULL on table.  For some reason it seems the query see's the ON match but the date filter eliminates the rows but I never get the table A row.

Comment: The 24 hour business day starts at 6:00am and runs to 5:59:59 the following morning, hence the date range even though it's only one business day.

Comment: clarification a few sentence above --- "so if there were no orders for that route for that day then the LEFT JOIN (table A) would not see any table B rows for that route and that day and return a NULL on table B".   Thanks

Comment: That all fits with what I could tell from yesterday. It still boils down to a simple outer join.

Comment: I kinda figured that, I just thought I'd describe the objective in case I was missing something.  Yeah that's what it seems to me as well, a simple outer join.....thanks again.  BTW if you have any additional thoughts please update this thread, not so much for now but to learn from and know the next time.  I'll check back occasionally just to see.  Thanks again.   And, I hope this site gives you the recognition, points/badges/etc.. however it works, for the effort and time you've given.  Please let me know if there's a way I can contribute to that.